# SED \n and \ into nothing

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

The people on this forum have been a tremendous help!  Thank you so much!

Here is my string

```
UEsDBBQAAAAIAKJBWEUdUIwScwwBAAB+AQAgAAAAQ29weV9vZl9kb2N1bWVudF9PY3QtMjQtMjAx\nNC5leGXsvXlcU0f0N5xAgICBRAVFRaVK3XfAigFFJYALGkSCKItWRMQNMVHrCl6ihGvc6lq1laKt\na11q3ZcgyKKouG+o2KJeDCoqCgpyn3Pm3ovY5X1\/zz\/
```

I'm trying to remove the \n  and the \ from the above string.

I've tried:

```
tr ‘\n\r\\’ ‘   ‘

sed 's/\n//g;s;\\;;g'
```

And a few other variations, but I'm not successful in stripping everything.  I can get the \ but not the n.

Does anyone see my error?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
sed 's/\\n//g;s/\\//g'
```

You want to remove a literal `\` followed by a literal `n`.  Consequently, the backslash has to be escaped in the first substitution.  By contrast, `s/\n//g` would remove newline characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use this with `tr` to delete (`-d`) all `\n` and `\`:

```
tr -d '\\n\\'
```

Test:

```
echo 'foo\nbar\foo' | tr -d '\\n\\'
```

Output:

```
foobarfoo
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do simply like this. You don't need to have another substitution.

```
sed 's/\\n\|\\//g'
```

OR

```
sed 's~\\n\|\\~~g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ var='UEsDBBQAAAAIAKJBWEUdUIwScwwBAAB+AQAgAAAAQ29weV9vZl9kb2N1bWVudF9PY3QtMjQtMjAx\nNC5leGXsvXlcU0f0N5xAgICBRAVFRaVK3XfAigFFJYALGkSCKItWRMQNMVHrCl6ihGvc6lq1laKt\na11q3ZcgyKKouG+o2KJeDCoqCgpyn3Pm3ovY5X1\/zz\/'
$ sed 's/\\n\|\\//g' <<<"$var"
UEsDBBQAAAAIAKJBWEUdUIwScwwBAAB+AQAgAAAAQ29weV9vZl9kb2N1bWVudF9PY3QtMjQtMjAxNC5leGXsvXlcU0f0N5xAgICBRAVFRaVK3XfAigFFJYALGkSCKItWRMQNMVHrCl6ihGvc6lq1laKta11q3ZcgyKKouG+o2KJeDCoqCgpyn3Pm3ovY5X1/zz/
```

**Explanation:**

Syntax of sed:

```
sed 's/pattern/replace/modifier' file
```

**Command:**

Splitted the above sed command like below for clarification.

```
sed 's/\\n\|\\//g'
```

- `s` - search and substitute.
- `\\n\|\\` - Pattern . `\\n` match a literal `\n` OR `\|` match a literal `\`. So at first it matches all the `\n` in the input string and then matches `\`
- `//` We have an empty replacement part, which means remove all the matched characters or replace the matched characters with an empty string.
- `g` - Global modifier. It makes the match to happen globally. ie, if two or more `\` symbols present on a single line, this `sed 's/\\//' file`  removes only the first `\` for each line. But the global modifier `g` forces `sed` to match all the existing `\` symbols.

---

Through GNU sed,

```
$ sed -r 's/\\n|\\//g' <<<"$var"
UEsDBBQAAAAIAKJBWEUdUIwScwwBAAB+AQAgAAAAQ29weV9vZl9kb2N1bWVudF9PY3QtMjQtMjAxNC5leGXsvXlcU0f0N5xAgICBRAVFRaVK3XfAigFFJYALGkSCKItWRMQNMVHrCl6ihGvc6lq1laKta11q3ZcgyKKouG+o2KJeDCoqCgpyn3Pm3ovY5X1/zz/
```

---

Through Perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's/\\n?//g' <<<"$var"
UEsDBBQAAAAIAKJBWEUdUIwScwwBAAB+AQAgAAAAQ29weV9vZl9kb2N1bWVudF9PY3QtMjQtMjAxNC5leGXsvXlcU0f0N5xAgICBRAVFRaVK3XfAigFFJYALGkSCKItWRMQNMVHrCl6ihGvc6lq1laKta11q3ZcgyKKouG+o2KJeDCoqCgpyn3Pm3ovY5X1/zz/
```

Comment: +1 but there's nothing GNU specific in your second sed. I mean, there is, the `-r` flag but that's not needed, you are using the exact saame command as your portable version and there are no features of extended regexes used.

Comment: only difference is `|` regex or pattern. i don't know what the title for the second one.

Comment: Ah! The escape, OK, sorry, I hadn't seen it.